# Should I use coordinates to handle dropzone with draggabilly

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, draggable, droppable

I'm using [draggabilly](https://github.com/desandro/draggabilly) in a project to make some element draggable. To know when the element is in a dropzone I use [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect) with the pointer from the drag event.

It give me something like this:

```
# I store boudings and element in an array
cards_bounding = []
matches = document.querySelectorAll("#board .card");
for match in matches
  bounding = match.getBoundingClientRect()
  cards_bounding.push(
    el: match
    bounding: 
      left: bounding.left
      right: bounding.right
      top: bounding.top
      bottom: bounding.bottom
  )

pointer_in_bounding = (pointer, bounding) ->
  bounding.left < pointer.pageX < bounding.right and bounding.top < pointer.pageY < bounding.bottom

# Then I check where is my pointer during the dragMove
drag_picked_card.on "dragMove", (draggieInstance, event, pointer) ->
  for card_bound in cards_bounding
    if pointer_in_bounding(pointer, card_bound.bounding)
      # …
```

Is it a better way to achieve this ?